# Can JWT be a replacement for session based authentication for web application?

Tags: authentication, web-applications, session-cookies, jwt

Can traditional session based authentications, as used in almost all web frameworks, be replaced by JWT; or was JWT designed with other clients (eg mobile first) in mind?

What are some downsides of using JWT as a replacement for cookie based session authentication?

Answer (score 3):

A JWT can indeed be a replacement for session based authentication since all information that is typically retained in the session, can now be included in a self-contained secured JSON object that is stored by the client. In case the client is a browser, the JWT may even be used as a session cookie in which case the JWT use case collapses with cookie based session authentication. A typical advantage of JWTs over cookies is that JWTs can be used across domains. A downside is that the size of a JWT is typically larger (because it contains more information and because of the crypto involved for protecting its contents).

Comment: Can you elaborate why JWT can cross domains?

Comment: when a JWT is presented in a header or a query/post parameter you can use it against protected resources in multiple domains whereas a cookie is applicable only to a single domain

Comment: Thanks! Well, I must admit I have read this article (https://stormpath.com/blog/where-to-store-your-jwts-cookies-vs-html5-web-storage/). It recommended to store token as cookies. And that's why I cannot understand how JWT can cross domains. Could you shed some light regarding this article?

Comment: It seems there're so many use/misuse of a single piece of technology.

Comment: I am the author of that referenced Stormpath blog post.  Using JWTs in cookies is possible to use across domains (or across subdomains). The answer to your question comes down to how to use cookies across domains with CORS. 

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS
http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/

Comment: well, that article explains that you can force cookies to be used in XMLHttpRequest; that does not mean that you can set a (single) cookie that will be used in XMLHttpRequests to different domains; of course you can use 2 JWTs in 2 cookies set by two different domains but that pushes the problem to how you set the two cookies in the first place